Does $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ represent the reals under addition or the positive reals?
I have seen $\mathbb{R}^+$ used in both contexts but I don't know if there's some way to tell the difference between the two... is there a different way to refer to either the reals under addition or the positive reals, when writing? Or do you just have hope readers will understand from context?

You can't really go wrong with $(\Bbb R,+)$.

$\langle \mathbb R, +\rangle$ is what I'm used to seeing for the reals under addition.

As you say,  it's used in both senses, unfortunately.  I prefer $\mathbb R_{>0}$ for the positive reals.

It should be clear from context, like most notation. I prefer it used to represent the positive real numbers.

$A^2=(A\circ A)$ for an operator $A$ while $A^2=A\cdot A$ for a matrix . It depends on the context doesn't it? If the writer is referring to the additive group of real numbers , in most cases , it will be specified (if not obvious by the context).

@AntonyTheo. That's a particularly bad example, I think.

Generally, as I have seen, $\mathbb{R}^+$ represents the positive reals or in some cases, the non negative reals. addition under the reals is denoted in group theory notation as $(\mathbb{R},+)$. notationally also just like in the case
$\mathbb{Z}^+$ for positive or non negative integers, this just makes the most sense
